# row_number() from table or view?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-view, row-number

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW public."masterx" AS 
 SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY st_distance(t1.geom, t2.geom)) AS rownum,
    t1.id_seq,
    t2.pars_id,
    st_distance(t1.geom, t2.geom) AS mesafe
   FROM kadas t2,v7 t1
  WHERE st_dwithin(t2.geom, t1.geom, 400::double precision) = true
  AND t1.datex > ('now'::text::date - '180 days'::interval);
```

It creates a view. When I use select from table it gives a result but when I select from the above view there is no result. What is the problem?

table t1 is

```
id_seq|field a | field b| geom|
```

table 2 is

```
id| field x  | field y | geom|
```

I want to join 2 tables with geom columns (both points).
__

```
SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY st_distance(t1.geom, t2.geom)) AS rownum,
    t1.id_seq,
    t2.id,
    st_distance(t1.geom, t2.geom) AS distance
   FROM table2 t2,table1 t1
  WHERE st_dwithin(t2.geom, t1.geom, 400::double precision) = true
```

If I try to select:

```
where t2.id= 12345
```

gives result in 1 second.

But when i use

```
create view as x (
SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY st_distance(t1.geom, t2.geom)) AS rownum,
        t1.id_seq,
        t2.id,
        st_distance(t1.geom, t2.geom) AS distance
       FROM table2 t2,table1 t1
      WHERE st_dwithin(t2.geom, t1.geom, 400::double precision) = true 
)
```

hen try to query on this view there is no result.
What is the problem?

it seems rownumber is problem here but why

__

table 1 v7 has 2 milyon row.
table 2  kadas t2 has 1 milyon row.

```
select * from masterx.  
where  pars_id =422328447
```

where is no solution.
what i want to do is:
select points in t1 that is in a buffer with t2 points in 400 meters and order them by distance. there is no problem to here but when I try to take row numbers by the distance for limiting the query for 100 first rows it makes db and comp mad and there is no solution**

Comment: Can you please show more?  It would help to see the queries that are failing, what you want them to return, what they are actually returning, and some data that they are operating upon.  _Try to create a minimal subset of the data that demonstrates the problem_.  You can add this information to your question by clicking on the "edit" link.

Comment: 1) Please show the *full query* you are using to select from your view.  2) Please show us some example data that exist in your underlying tables kadas and v7, plus the results you expect to get from your view for that sample data.  3) Have you tested the query used in your view *before* trying to put it in to a view?

Comment: Thank you for the additional information.  I think some more may be necessary.  When you say "there is no solution," do you mean that the query returns no rows, or do you mean that the query so long that you or your program times out?  Also: When describing your tables in the question, use the `\d` command in psql, for example, `\d table1'.  That will show the column names _and_ types, indices, and so on.  If this is a performance problem, then also add the result of using the "explain" command on your query.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but I would simplify the `CREATE` statement like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW public.masterx AS 
SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY st_distance(t1.geom, t2.geom)) AS rownum,
       t1.id_seq,
       t2.pars_id,
       st_distance(t1.geom, t2.geom) AS mesafe
FROM   v7    t1
JOIN   kadas t2 ON st_dwithin(t1.geom, t2.geom, 400::float8)
WHERE  t1.datex > (now()::date - 180)
ORDER  BY 1;
```

`'now'` is a constant, I assume you want the function now() instead. [Per documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT):

> Tip: You do not want to use the third form (`'now'`) when specifying a `DEFAULT`
>   clause while creating a table. The system will convert now to a
>   timestamp as soon as the constant is parsed, so that when the default
>   value is needed, the time of the table creation would be used!

You can subtract `integer` from `date`.
And you shouldn't rely on the sort order derived from the window function. Add an explicit `ORDER BY`.

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM public.masterx
```

#### Performance

You have 1 million x 2 million rows. That's 2,000,000,000,000 possible combinations. Your condition  `t1.datex > (now()::date - 180)` reduces one side somewhat, but a *huge* number will remain. Appropriate indexes on the geom columns help a lot. That can explain why, 
with the condition

```
where t2.id = 12345
```

.. it only takes 1 second. You have reduced the operation by a factor of 1 million. Without that condition it takes ~ *1 million times* as long ...